# TypeScript the unintrusive way: Can I use typescript with definition files only (and normal js files)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have a project that wants to work with plain JavaScript and using a language that just compiles to JavaScript is out of the question, but I still want the benefits of static type checking and code completion in my IDE: Could I still use TypeScript, but keep all those additions in (external) .d.ts files?

Are there any limitations I should be aware of if I attempt this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems (at least):

- How does your IDE know that although it is editing a Javascript file, it should perform Typescript type validation and completion ? JSDoc however is correctly supported in many IDEs
- Type Definition Files contain definitions only. Type inference needs the whole implementation to work correctly.

Comment: btw, what is wrong with 'a language that just compiles to Javascript' ?

Answer (score 0):

> using a language that just compiles to JavaScript is out of the question, but I still want the benefits of static type checking

Have a look at google closure tools : https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

That's what many people used *before* (and still do after) TypeScript.

Comment: typescript is better though.. its cleaner, inline and less verbose

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly use the JavaScript files generated from the typescript, in a project. The project doesn't need to know it was created from TypeScript. You don't even need the type-definition files. The generated js files don't have type information. The type information is only for developer's convenience, it is not needed by the browser.